# Problem in writing a razor code in Script

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, razor

This is my code. I want to create two textboxes using Razor in script.

the `model=>model[i].Name1` is not woring

```
    var counter = 0;
    @{
        int i = 0;
    }
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#addButton").click(function () {
            if (counter < 0) {
                alert("Add more textbox");
                return false;
            }
            i = counter;
            var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('div'))
                .attr("id", 'TextBoxDiv' + counter).attr("class", 'TextBoxDiv').attr("style", "border:5px solid green");
            newTextBoxDiv.after().html('<label>Name #'+ counter + ': </label>' +
                '@Html.EditorFor(model => model[i].Name1);' +
                '<br/> <label>Email #'+ counter +': </label>' +
               '@Html.EditorFor(model => model[i].EmailID);' +
                '<br/><input type="button" name="button' + counter +
                '" class="removeButton" id="removeButton' + counter + '" value="Remove Button" onclick="remove(this)">');
                   newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#TextBoxesGroup");
                   alert(i.toString());
                   counter++;
                   i = i + 1;
        });
    });
```

Comment: What do you mean by it's not working? Is it not getting value at all or only on the first?. Maybe you need to do `@{i++}` and not `i = i + 1`

Comment: JQuery/Javascript = _client side_,  Razor = _server side_

Comment: the array i used in razor code is not woring  model=>model[i].Name1;

Comment: I am creating a view where user can add multiple names & emails and save them at one click. i have created a model which has Name1, EmailID as fields. Then i created a controller and add View i need my view can send an array of names & emails to the controller. but when i using the script it only send one name and array to the controller i.e. model[0].Name1 and model[0].Email.
i know there is a problem in the script because when i hard code the script it accepts values as i hard code.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get JS to write out Razor - the JS happens client side AFTER the razor has been executed on the server and sent to the client. the JS won't know what to do with the razor syntax.

In this case, you would need to manually create the html which the Razor helper would make for you. It should still parse back into razor, providing you put the html in the right format (right name, id etc)

So write out the  and make the name field match what the razor would have generated.

Comment: But when i replace model[i].Name1 to model[0].Name1, model[1].Name1, model[2].Name1, model[3].Name1 it is working.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set a js variable with the value of model,and then use `<input/>` to replace `@Html.EditorFor()`:

```
var counter = 0;
var m = JSON.parse('@Json.Serialize(@Model)');
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#addButton").click(function () {
            if (counter < 0) {
                alert("Add more textbox");
                return false;
            }
            var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('div'))
                .attr("id", 'TextBoxDiv' + counter).attr("class", 'TextBoxDiv').attr("style", "border:5px solid green");
            newTextBoxDiv.after().html('<label>Name #'+ counter + ': </label>' +
                '<input id="model_' + counter +'__Name1" name=" model[' + counter + '].Name1" value="' + m[counter].Name1 + '"/>' +
                '<br/> <label>Email #'+ counter +': </label>' +
               '<input id="model_' + counter +'EmailID" name=" model[' + counter + '].EmailID" value="' + m[counter].EmailID + '"/>' +
                '<br/><input type="button" name="button' + counter +
                '" class="removeButton" id="removeButton' + counter + '" value="Remove Button" onclick="remove(this)">');
                   newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#TextBoxesGroup");
                   counter++;
        });
    });
```